# Antlr4 TokenStreamRewriter delete tokens after X in line

Tags: token, antlr4

I am using Antlr4 9.2 and have the following language translation query.

Every text line that ! want is 66 characters, the rest I want discarded. The bold stuff.

''**************************************************************''**17002700006873***

''* £ACT£X 0603170027   A  001   C  001   D  001               *''**17002700006874***

How do I write a TokenStreamRewriter that deletes the characters after the 66 char? before these get to the tokeniser?

Answer (score 1):

The TokenStreamRewriter acts on a TokenStream that is created by the tokenizer, so it doesn't act on anything before the tokenizer.

I assume that you need to tokenize the content of those first 66 characters.
You should probably look into using some preprocessing to truncate each line and then hand that input to the tokenizer.

While you *could* use a different, very simple tokenizer, to first tokenize, and then use a TokenStreamRewriter, to rewrite a new character stream to pass to the "real" tokenizer, this would really just be a very "tortured" way to just write a loop that reads input line by line, and only writes out the first 66 characters to a new stream, that you could then tokenize.

TokenStreamRewriters are very handy tools to take an existing tokenStream and manipulate the contents to produce a new String (they do not produce a new TokenStream)

Comment: Okay so delete the items from the line before we pass to the tokeniser, via a pre-processor. That seems a limitation that the tool should be able to compensate for , but I understand the response. Thx again. P..s Yes I do need to tokensie the first 66 chars.

Comment: "seems a limitation that the tool should be able to compensate for": I disagree. By facilitating such a  feature, you'd get a context sensitive lexer (only tokenise X chars after a line-break), which is not how ANTLR is designed. A preprocessor is the easiest and most simple way to do what you want.